# Xbox Live accounts in family cannot play my games on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network

I have an Xbox Live account I'd used for years with my Xbox 360. We bought an Xbox One recently and I downloaded some games as my user. My son also has an Xbox Live account but cannot play my downloaded games, even though he's in my "family" on XBox Live and it's on the same console.

Is there anything we need to do to get him access to my games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After speaking to an MS support rep, the issue is that I hadn't designated the new XBox One as my "home" xbox. You need to go into the Settings, then set as home the console you want to share with the family.

After that, any user using my "home" XBox (whether my family or not) can use all my DLC and Gold games.

Answer (score -2):

Try uninstalling the game. Then re-install it. If it doesn't work go to the xbox support page and see if they can help you that way. Here's the link for the support page... http://support.xbox.com/en-US/?xr=shellnav